# Simple quadratic, crazy question part 2

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994122/simple-quadratic-crazy-question), I asked for advice on a general method to solve a specific problem. Many good ideas came from this, but the problem I gave was too simple and these approaches were sufficient for that specific case but not the more general form. I have a PARI program which grinds to a halt at a certain size, so this I will present for input on a method to solve.

Find a number C, or show that C exists, such that:
$x^2-397x-C=0$ has integer roots, and furthermore,
All of the primes from 2 to 19 (inclusive) are factors of C, and no other prime divides C. These factors can be to any integer exponents > 0.

Thank you!

Comment: so you're asking if there's two integers $397$ apart whose prime factors are all the primes up to $19$ ?

Comment: Precisely! Again, I stress that those prime factors can be repeated, i.e. $2^53^45^6...$ Note that some of the primes will be factors of the one number, some will be factors of the other number, but the two numbers will be relatively prime, since 397 is a prime.

Comment: To find values of $c$ yielding integer roots, it suffices to find the (integer) values of $c$ such that $397^2 + 4c$ is a perfect square

Comment: Agreed, but this is not easy to find given the factorization of C as stated. Your comment, Omnomnomnom, is what I based my PARI program on, it can find many squares that fit, but none of them have the required factorization for C. BTW, my conjecture works for all primes p less than 397 and having factorization of C using all primes less than the square root of p. Again, I want to stress that it would be sufficient to prove that such a C exists, I don't really need to find it.

Comment: I thought about using a hyperbolic approach, and using pell's equation, since we could write this as ${D^2 \over p^2}-{4c \over p^2}=1$ but then we have to split c into factors which are square and those which are not.

Comment: The "p" in the above comment is the 397. " $D^2$ " is the perfect square that Omnomnomnom was talking about.

Comment: I must admit that my complex analysis is shaky, so I wonder if anyone could explain in simple terms how this post is related to the one titled "Relation between the Dedekind Zeta Function and Quadratic Reciprocity". I have looked at those topics but have not had enough time to learn them well. But supposedly they are related

Comment: @AaronHorak there are no 2 coprime numbers 397 apart whose prime factors are all the primes up to 19 up to exponent 3. It is likely there are none for any higher exponents.

Answer (score 1):

## Updated

There are no $2$ coprime numbers $397$ apart whose prime factors are all the primes up to $19$ up to exponent $3$.

There are integers that meet the conditions required at the following distances apart:

$23, 31, 37, 41, 59, 61, 67, 79, 83, 89, 97, 103, 127, 131, 149, 151, 
173, 179, 191, 193, 199, 211, 223, 227, 233, 239, 241, 251, 263, 271, 
281, 283, 307, 313, 347, 367, 379, 389, 401, 421,\dots$

Comment: thanks for your response. Keep in mind that C can be the product of those primes, each to their own exponent. So I'm not really sure what you were going for, unless your intent is to split up C into the product of 2 numbers, so that it would look like $x^2-397x-a\times b=0$ where ab=C. What you have would simplify to $x^2-397x-397a-a^2$ and I'm not sure how that could help. maybe you could explain? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for being so thorough. My full conjecture might shed some light on things at this point. It is that, given a prime number p, there exists c such that $x^2-px-c=0$ has integer roots and c is the product of (positive powers of) all of the primes less than $\sqrt{p}$. So, for a prime like 29, c would only have 2, 3, and 5 as factors. Given this setup, all of the primes fit the conjecture up to 397, though some of the exponents are higher than 3 (which is what makes me sure that it might still be possible for 397).I need to find a way to post my program, maybe you can make it run faster.

Comment: @AaronHorak please do. I don't know PARI though - just use Mathematica.

Comment: re your conjecture, I am fairly sure it holds from what I have been looking at.

Comment: Thank you I am too, but I need to actually prove it! I've spent most of my life on this. I will need to look up mathematica language, it has been a while. There are shortcuts in PARI mathematica might not have, like a command (omega) that counts the number of unique prime factors. But if it doesn't have it, I'm sure I can make it work, it just might be slower.

Comment: It is probably more instructive to look at lower ranges (primes up to 13 for instance) - primes missed out of lists are power 2 : {17, 31, 37, 71, 89, 107, 139, 157}
power 3 : {71, 89}
power 4 : {71, 89}
power 5 : {89} ...

Comment: ... up to 169 that is.

Comment: @AaronHorak you might also want to look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/if-the-sum-of-positive-integers-a-and-b-is-a-prime-their-gcd-is-1-proof) if you haven't already

Comment: Not sure what you mean "missed out of the list", for example 17 only needs factors of 2 and 3: $x^2-17x-5184=0$ works (5184=81*64), and the factors needed for 31 are 2, 3, and 5, and $x^2-31x-4050$ works, where 4050 is 81*50.

Comment: @AaronHorak sure, but including *all* prime factors up to 13 requires going up to power 3.

Comment: @AaronHorak BTW If you don't need to use *all* prime factors up to $19$, you can just use $2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 11-5\cdot 13=397$

Comment: @AaronHorak also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112113/sum-of-integers-squared-relatively-prime-to-and-less-than-n)

Answer (score 0):

SQRT(397<sup>2</sup> + 4C) should be a perfect square as  Omnomnomnom said.

When does that happen?

397<sup>2</sup>/4 is 39402.25

We can rewrite

SQRT(397<sup>2</sup> + 4C) = SQRT(4 * 39402 + 1 + 4(A - 39402))

= SQRT( 1 + 4A)

And if these number have to be a perfect square, then

N<sup>2</sup> = 1 + 4A

A = (N<sup>2</sup> - 1)/4

C = (N<sup>2</sup> - 1)/4 - 39402, where N are the odd natural numbers.

Comment: Thank you, this might make my program faster (with some adjustments to generalize it - if I replace 397 with p, we have that $C=({N^2-1} \over 4}-int({p^2 \over 4})$. We still need to prove that there exists some C, defined as you have, which has the prime factors of 2, ..., 19. It's a nice, compact form though. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, this might make my program faster (with some adjustments to generalize it - if I replace 397 with p, we have that $C=({N^2-1 \over 4}-int({p^2 \over 4}))$. We still need to prove that there exists some C, defined as you have, which has the prime factors of 2, ..., 19. (or 2... $sqrt(p)$) It's a nice, compact form though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the quadratic formula, we find that the square root of the discriminant must be an odd integer. in other words, $\sqrt{397^2-4C}$ is perfect.
We set $397^2-4C=p^2$ for an integer $p.$ So now, we take note that $C=9699690x$ for some integer $x$ due to the restriction.

Although this is more general, we can plug it in to get $397^2-4\cdot9699690C=p^2.$ However, it is evident only $0$ will make $397^2-4\cdot9699690C$ be positive, which we need by the Trivial Inequality.
Every prime divides zero, so there are no solutions.

Note that some of the restrictions, such as $p$ is an odd integer, and $x$ must only have $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19$ as factors, were not used.